# BeanELResolver error on Websphere

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jstl

Below is my code of the controller , which returns a view .
Its working perfect if i deploy and run on Tomcat 7 , but the problem persist while same is deployed on Websphere .

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/review_and_confirm_travel_detail.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView confirmTravelDetails(@ModelAttribute ViewQuote  viewQuote , 
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Model model) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<String> stopsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    RequestBuilderUtil.getStopsRequestString(viewQuote.getStopsValuesForRequest() , stopsList , this);

    List<String > specialInputList = getSpecialInputString(viewQuote.getSpecialInputs());
    List<String> specialInputValues = getSpecialInputString(viewQuote.getSpecialInputValues());
    Map<String , String > spInputMap =getSpecialInputMap(viewQuote.getSpecialInputs(), viewQuote.getSpecialInputValues());
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("review_and_confirm_travel_detail");
    modelAndView.addObject("specialInputList", specialInputList);
    modelAndView.addObject("specialInputValues", specialInputValues);
    modelAndView.addObject("specialInputMap", spInputMap);
    modelAndView.addObject("stopsList", stopsList);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Also , following is the part of JSP which causes the error .

```
    <div class="table_review_confirm_travel_left">
    <table id= "specialInputTable"align="center" valign="top" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="td-padding1">

        <tr><td  colspan="2" style="padding-left:5px; background-color:#e1e1e1;font-weight:bold">
                Special Inputs
            </td>
        </tr>
        <core:forEach items="${specialInputMap}" var= "spInput">
        <core:if test="${!spInput.equals('')}">
        <tr><td nowrap style="padding-left: 20px;">
                ${spInput.key}
            </td>
            <td nowrap style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <input id ="specialInputName" type="hidden" name="specialInputName" value="${spInput.key}">
                <input type="text" placeholder="${spInput.value}" name="specialInputValue" onkeypress="return validateAlphaNumeric(event)">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </core:if>
    <!--    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var inputName ="";
        $(function () {
            var specialInputName = document.getElementById('specialInputName');
            inputName = inputName + specialInputName.value();
        });

        </script> -->
        </core:forEach>
    </table>    
</div>
```

You could go though the following line , these are the error logs from the server .:

> [2/23/14 23:40:06:697 EST] 00000166 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [/WEB-INF/views/review_and_confirm_travel_detail.jsp] in application [CESDirect_war]. Exception created : [javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
>           at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:480)
>           at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:137)
>           at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:162)
>           at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:44)
>           at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:778)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_if_6(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:565)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_forEach_1(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:613)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_if_5(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:657)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_form_form_0(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:952)
>           at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspService(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:267)
>           at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
>           at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>           at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>           at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>           at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>           at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
>           at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
>           at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:77)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
>           at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
>           ... 49 more
>   ]

```
[2/23/14 23:40:06:701 EST] 00000166 LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called.
[2/23/14 23:40:06:706 EST] 00000166 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause dispatcher: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:480)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:137)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:162)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:44)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:778)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_if_6(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:565)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_forEach_1(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:613)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_if_5(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:657)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_form_form_0(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:952)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspService(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:267)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:77)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
        ... 49 more

[2/23/14 23:40:06:741 EST] 00000166 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[dispatcher]: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:480)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:137)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:162)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:44)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:283)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:778)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_if_6(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:565)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_forEach_1(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:613)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_core_if_5(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:657)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspx_meth_form_form_0(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:952)
        at com.ibm._jsp._review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail._jspService(_review_5F_and_5F_confirm_5F_travel_5F_detail.java:267)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.el.BeanELResolver can not access a member of class java.util.MapEntry with modifiers "public"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:77)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
        ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a pretty similar issue myself and turns out it's a difference in behaviour between tomcat and websphere's EL implementation.
I think this is complaining (in a not very obvious way) that the class type it is trying to use reflection on to access the equals method from isn't a public class so reflection access control fails.

Specifically to this snippet

```
<core:forEach items="${specialInputMap}" var= "spInput">
 <core:if test="${!spInput.equals('')}">
```

I think this puts an object of class type `java.util.MapEntry` into the `spInput` variable and the ELResolver then goes through the methods in the MapEntry class to find the equals method but when try to invoke the equals method find the MapEntry class isn't publicly accessible.

Not sure what that `java.util.MapEntry`class is though, doesn't look like standard sun jdk one.

If you change to use a different type of Map impl to pass the jsp you might be able to work around the issue.

In my case I was getting a list back whose class type was only package visibility and calling size on it in the jsp i.e. `<c:when test="${mylist.size() == 1}">`which would be fine in normal code as calls the public method size via the List interface but the EL procesor for Websphere uses reflection to invoke the method on package private class and gets a security error. We changed to return a standard ArrayList instead to workaround the issue.

Looks like the tomcat impl returns the method from the interface a class implements if the class is not public so it's a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to document another reason that can cause this issue.  I ran into the exact same error message when the jsp used

```
${entry.getKey()}
```

instead of

```
${entry.key}
```

The former is acceptable in the tomcat implementation but causes the exception in websphere.